# Magento 2 Custom cron job is ignored

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab

I have followed the tutorial on [Magento dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-tut.html) to create a custom crontab. Checking the cron_schedule table and various logs, I can see that cron is successfully running M2 jobs (e.g. indexer, mailers), but not the custom crontab. There is no mention of it at all - no errors in the Magento or server logs; no entry in cron_schedule.

I have manually run cron serveral times, seeing the message "Ran jobs by schedule" each time. I have set cron to log to var/log/magento.cron.log, and there I see only the same "Ran jobs by schedule" message - no other output from the other M2 cron jobs which I know are running (because they show status "success" in cron_schedule).

The custom module crontab (etc/crontab.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="cronjob_default" instance="Vex\SportIntBase\import\StoredProcCronDefault" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

The class:

```
namespace Vex\SportIntBase\import;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class StoredProcCronDefault
{
    protected $_logger;
    private $_fetchers;

    const PATH = __DIR__ . 'vendor/vex/module-sport-int-base/import';

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_fetchers = array(
            'price_fetch.php',
            'products_fetch.php',
            'stock_fetch.php'
        );
    }

    public function execute() {
        $this->_logger->info('Beginning VexSport Stored Procedure Run (default)');
        foreach($this->_fetchers as $runSP) {
            include(SELF::$PATH) . $runSP;
        }
    }
}
```

Version info: M2 2.1.2, PHP 7.0.13, Debian 8.6.

Thanks for any ideas or suggestions. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is Usefull for you,

You need to use **n98-magerun2** this will show all the error in cron jobs,

**Download and Install Phar File**

```
<m2-dir>$ wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar
```

After seen in  have **n98-magerun2.phar** file. with in m2-directory

next you need to list all the cron jobs, follow this command:

```
<m2 -dir> $ ./n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:list
```

then, run cron job:

```
<m2- dir> $ ./n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run [cron jobname]
```

This will show you where error occur in your code.

follow this [link](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2)

Comment: n98-magerun.phar is just for M1, while the author is asking for M2 solution

Comment: @PYYick  i updated my answer, check it `n98-magerun2.phar `  is there in magento 2

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the log on the folder: /project/var/log

Anyway, you can test with a script for logs:
For Magento <= 2.4.2

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/logfile.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Simple Text Log'); // Simple Text Log
$logger->info('Array Log'.print_r($myArrayVar, true)); // Array Log
```

For Magento >= 2.4.2

```
$writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Your text message');
$data = ["test" => "testing"];
$logger->debug(var_export($data, true));
```

So run cronjob by hand:

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```