# Why my CRON job cannot run? Is it related to my default setting?

Tags: magento-2.1, cron

I have a `etc/cron_groups.xml` set as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/cron_groups.xsd">
    <group id="cron_group_name">
        <schedule_generate_every>180</schedule_generate_every>
        <schedule_ahead_for>10</schedule_ahead_for>
        <schedule_lifetime>20</schedule_lifetime>
        <history_cleanup_every>10</history_cleanup_every>
        <history_success_lifetime>1440</history_success_lifetime>
        <history_failure_lifetime>43200</history_failure_lifetime>
        <use_separate_process>1</use_separate_process>
    </group>
</config>
```

I noticed that if I follow the default settings on http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-ref.html, the CRON job can run properly. As I want to run CRON job every 3 hours, I set `<schedule_generate_every>` to 180, and adjusted other attributes as above. Have I done sth wrong on the settings?

Comment: run `php bin/magento cron:run` command from your terminal and check `cron_schedule` table in database. Try to run the command twice and check does your job entry in database

Comment: follow this answer, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149276/magento-2-custom-cron-job-is-ignored/149278#149278  its throw any error in your cron job code.

Comment: @userpk No entry on databases.

Comment: @Rajkumar.E It shows **Done**

Comment: check your `cron_schedule` table , status of your cron jobs

Comment: @Rajkumar.E The job status is **success**

Comment: @ your cron job is running, check your code(add  log to our code or print any value, then run cron using  n98-magerun2.phar, check your code running correctly.)

Comment: OK, I got my CRON job running now, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

After studying the codes in the core, I attempt to modify the value of `<schedule_ahead_for>` and `<schedule_lifetime>`. I changed back to the default value on the reference suggested. OK, it runs again.

After that, I changed the value of `<schedule_ahead_for>` and `<schedule_lifetime>`. I found out if the value of `<schedule_ahead_for>` is **larger** than `<schedule_lifetime>`, then CRON job may not write into the `cron_schedule` table. That caused the CRON job didn't run on schedule.

So, my final decision is: it's OK to follow the default value of `etc/cron_groups.xml`. As long as the schedule is not near the schedule time, the system will not add a record on `cron_schedule` table.